# Using Orbeon Form Builder, can I copy the chosen text from a dropdown to another text field instead of the value?

Tags: forms, dropdown, orbeon

I want to copy the text from a dropdown to a separate text field, not the value. This becomes a problem when I have multiple language versions. Because all dropdown language versions can have different labels (set by which language you choose), but all have the same value.

For example, if I have a dropdown of colors in different languages (changes by what language you choose), I want to show the color that is chosen (in whatever language) in a separate text field.

Is this possible? I’m using Orbeon Forms 2016.3.

Comment: Good question. It is possible, but I understand it isn't trivial. You can find more on this in my answer below, and you'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Just curious, Aelin: did you get a chance to try using `xxf:itemset()`, per my answer below? If so, did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the [`xxf:itemset()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/controls-functions#xxf-itemset) function, which tells you, for a selection control, everything about the possible choices users can make, including the labels and corresponding values.

However, once caveat is that itemsets re-evaluate during refresh which means that this function can't be used reliably in a calculate or other formula: it can only be used when responding to an event, which you can do in a [custom model](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom-dialogs-model-logic):

1. I'll assume that your form as a selection control named `color` and a selection control named `color-label`.
2. Create a file for you custom model, say  `WEB-INF/resources/forms/resources/model.xml`, with the content below.

   ```
   <xf:model xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
       <xf:setvalue
           observer="color-control"
           event="xforms-enabled xforms-value-changed"
           ref="xxf:binding('color-label-control')"
           value="
               if (xxf:binding('color-control') = '')
               then ''
               else
                   xxf:itemset('color-control', 'xml')/itemset/choices/item[
                       value = xxf:binding('color-control')
                   ]/label"/>
   </xf:model>
   ```
3. Reference your custom model by adding the following property to your `properties-local.xml`:

   ```
   <property 
       as="xs:anyURI"
       name="oxf.fr.detail.model.custom.*.*"
       value="oxf:/forms/resources/model.xml"/>`
   ```